# Erlang map nested list

Tags: list, erlang, nested

I have i list:

```
[["asd", "ddsa"], ["ASD", "ASD"], ["FH", "SDFDF]].
```

How can i applicate function F to each element of this list? How can i map this list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If assuming by element you mean "asd", your main List will always be two levels deep as in your example and your returned result shall be in the same format, this will due.

```
List1 = [["asd", "ddsa"], ["ASD", "ASD"], ["FH", "SDFDF]]
[ [ F(String) || String <- List2 ] || List2 <- List1 ]
```

If you mean that your element is ["asd","ddsa"] just use lists:map/2 or list comprehension as below.

```
List1 = [["asd", "ddsa"], ["ASD", "ASD"], ["FH", "SDFDF]]
[ F(List2) || List2 <- List1 ]
```

Comment: And if you want to flatten the list and return an unnested list of values you would do `[ F(String) || SubList <- List, String <- SubList ]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a `deepMap` function, performing something like:

```
deepMap(Fun, T) ->
  case is_list(T) of
    true -> lists:map(fun(E) -> deepMap(Fun,E) end, T);
    false -> Fun(T)
  end.
```

If the input is not a list, evaluate your function. If it is a list, apply `deepMap` to all elements using `map`, using your function.

Comment: In this case you'd actually need different code since strings are lists too. This code would call Fun for each character (integer).